# Iterate through a scene and return the location value of all objects and append to a created JSON file as a Set or Dict

Tags: python, objects, transforms, file-browser

I am trying to iterate through a scene and return the world space location data for each object in the scene. I want to zip this data into a dictionary with name, x, y, and Z being the keys and the values of those keys are appended to JSON file that is created and lists out the objects and their transforms.

Originally, I was using the dumps method, but I am new and I know I am doing something wrong, the JSON file only returns the last selected objects' data, not all of the scene's objects.

In the end, I opted for printing a lonely text file, which does work but is not like a fancy JSON file. My process involves:

1. -resetting the mesh origin
2. -capturing that location data as Name = Key and Value = Location as tuple
3. -Return the mesh transform to Zero.
4. -Save location to JSON with structured data

So what am I doing wrong, and which code does not work? I am struggling with zipping this dictionary with the name and the tuple.  How do I append to this dictionary and then to the JSON file as it iterates through the scene objects?

```
import bpy
import os




C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)     
data_name = os.path.join(directory, "Scene_Coordinates.txt")   

file = open(data_name, 'w')

objs = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects
      if obj.type == "MESH"]
          
      
      

override = bpy.context.copy()
override["selected_editable_objects"] = objs
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(override, type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

obs = {}


for col in D.collections:
    col.name
    for o in col.objects:
        name = o.name
        locX = o.location.x
        locY = o.location.y
        locZ = o.location.z
        
        obs["name"] = name
        obs['X'] = locX
        obs['Y'] = locY
        obs['Z'] = locZ
        data = file.write(name + ' Locaton = ' +str(locX)+ ', ' +str(locY)+ ', ' +str(locZ)+ '\n\n')
        
    

           
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)     
data_name = os.path.join(directory, "Scene_Coordinates.txt")      

objs = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects
      if obj.type == "MESH"]
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=False, scale=False)
```

Comment: Uh, the given code just messes with origin positions. It does nothing to record them to a JSON file. Wrong code snippet? Also, this seems more of a Python question than a blender one: The same question could likely apply to a completely different set of data being written to file.

Comment: It is resetting the pivot points. it is recording the location and then freezes the transforms again and records the world position and name to a text file, I was also able to get it to write a JSON file but only one iteration, so I cannot get the JSON to write per iteration

Comment: While it is a python File System based question, Blender API handles this differently so it is Blender Specific

Comment: Are you sure it handles the differently? I mean, you’re the one stuck on the subject, so by definition your information can’t possibly be complete.

Comment: Did you ever close the file later in the code? If you don’t close it or flush it, the data is not actually written.